# PHP Form validation logic is a little off

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, error-handling

I am validating an HTML Form with PHP. All of my code is fine, except the message field. If I put something in the message field and the other fields are displaying errors, it still submits. But, if I put something into the other fields and the other fields have errors, it won't submit, which is correct. I suspect it has something to do with the last if-else of my code. Thank you in advance.

```
contact.php
<?php

include 'includes/config.php';
$errors = FALSE;
$displayErrors = NULL;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Connect to MYSQL Database server
$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL Database.");
$result = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connect) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL table.");

//Clean Data to prevent malicous injections
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($first))));
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($last))));
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($email))));
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($subject))));
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($message))));

if (empty($first)) {
    $errors = TRUE;
    $displayErrors .= 'First name is invalid.<br/>';
}
if (empty($last)) {
    $errors = TRUE;
    $displayErrors .= 'Last name is invalid.<br/>';
}
if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors = TRUE;
    $displayErrors .= 'Email is invalid.<br/>';
}
if (empty($subject)) {
    $errors = TRUE;
    $displayErrors .= 'Subject is invalid.<br/>';
}
if (empty($message)) {
    $errors = TRUE;
    $displayErrors .= 'Message is invalid.<br/>';
} else {
    $errors = FALSE;
          //Database insertion goes here
    echo 'Form submission successful. Thank you ' . $first . '.';

}

}
?>
```

Comment: I'd remove the last else and just do another if ($errors == TRUE) //do something else submit

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I knew it was a small problem haha.

Comment: Yep, simple newbie mistake :) Make sure you accept an answer when you can

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() did not modify the passed string, it returns the modified string, so all the calls there are useless, because they don't have any effect to the given variables.

Comment: I should add them to the variables at the top, right?

Comment: yeah he's right. Something like `$message = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($_POST['message']))));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

I've tidied your logic, instead of using `$error=true` ect you should build an error array (containing your error text) and then check if thats empty at the end, I also cleaned up the magic quotes problem it seems your having, and the horrid multiple mysql_real_escape_string's, hope it helps

contact.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/config.php';
//Connect to MYSQL Database server
$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL Database.");
$result = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connect) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL table.");

$errors = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    function clean(&$value){
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($value)));
        }else{
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($value));
        }
    }
    array_walk($_POST,'clean');


    if (empty($_POST['first'])) {
        $errors['first']= 'First name is invalid.<br/>';
    }else{
        $first = $_POST['first'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['last'])) {
        $errors['last']= 'Last name is invalid<br/>';
    }else{
        $last = $_POST['last'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is invalid.<br/>';
    }else{
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['subject'])) {
        $errors['subject']= 'Subject is invalid.<br/>';
    }else{
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $errors['message']= 'Message is invalid.<br/>';
    }else{
        $message = $_POST['messsage'];
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
        //Database insertion goes here
        echo 'Form submission successful. Thank you ' . htmlentities($first) . '.';
    }else{
        //Errors, so your have $errors['name'] ect to output
        //so somthing like:
        echo (isset($errors['name'])?$errors['name']:null);

    }

}
?>
```

You should also perhaps add a condition that the value is a min certain length, with `strlen($_POST['first']) > 2` ect.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are saying, if the message is not empty then `$errors=FALSE`, but you don't take into account all the other fields.

I'd suggest putting the errors in an array like:

```
$errors['email'] = true;
```

Then checking that array at the end using a `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

Try turning that `else` into

```
if($errors == FALSE) {//just corrected the equality operator
    //Database insertion goes here
    echo 'Form submission successful. Thank you ' . $first . '.'
}
```

Comment: This solution worked too! I knew it was a small problem ahaha. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make all your ifs else ifs
that way your last else will not mess up your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Before all of those ifs, you should put $errors = FALSE. Then instead of the else at the end of your code, you can put if(!$errors){ //database insertion here }